# WPS processing WFS 2.0 INSPIRE data

Tags: wfs, geoprocessing-service, gml, wps, inspire

I am writing in the hopes that there is somebody here that might know/use a GIS server solution, that has WPS functionality which would allow me to use data from a WFS 2.0.0 GIS service, which serves GML 3.2 data.

An example of service I am trying to use is this INSPIRE download service:

http://inspire.biodiversity.ro/WFS/RO_ENV_PS/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&TypeName=ps:ProtectedSite&featureid=RONPA0056

From what I read, WPS services can't process data from a WFS directly, and first needs to read the geometries in memory, to be then able to geoprocess.

I have tried several tools from the Geoserver 2.7, using the demo WPS interface to create processing requests however there seems to be no support for WFS 2.0 and GML 3.2 geometries. I have tried using the process vec:CollectGeometries but it only supports WFS 1.1 or WFS 1.0 and not the WFS 2.0 standard.

Does anyone have a way of working with the service above?

Comment: I have tested the collect geometries WPS process with sucess when using a local geoserver dataset from a reference such as: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&TypeName=sorin-tni:ro_judete&featureid=ro_judete.2

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a real WFS as it doesn't respond to getCapabilities requests

Comment: @iant I get a [GetCapabilities response](http://inspire.biodiversity.ro/WFS/RO_ENV_PS/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&) from the service.  It appears it is strictly following the WFS rules for KVP, i.e. the request value must be _GetCapabilities_ any other spelling is incorrect.

Comment: @nmtoken well spotted

Answer (score 1):

This how [PyWPS](http://www.pywps.org) (versions 3 and 4) deals with this kind of request:

1. Uses the service URL passed as argument to fetch whatever data is served.
2. Creates a file in the disk with whatever data was retrieved.
3. Provides your process with a pointer to the file.

In case the data retrieved is GML 3.2, you then need something to help you read it. For that you have the [GDAL/OGR Python bindings](http://gdal.org/python/) or simpler libraries such as [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona/).

Answer (score 1):

From the [capabilities request](http://inspire.biodiversity.ro/WFS/RO_ENV_PS/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities) the service supports versions 1.0 and 1.1 so simply request a lower WFS version and GML and use the GeoServer WPS as you want to.